# What effect \StartShownPreambleCommands has?

Tags: xetex, packages, preamble

It seems to me that the `XeTeX` is completely insensitive to where do I put
`\StartShownPreambleCommands` or to whether I comment it out.

My Q. is what is the intended effect of this command `\StartShownPreambleCommands` ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{ttctexa}

\StartShownPreambleCommands
\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{6}
\setlength\textwidth{159.0pt}

%\StartShownPreambleCommands
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\StopShownPreambleCommands
\begin{document}
The right column shows the input text to be treated by
\LaTeX{} with preamble material shown in blue. In the
left column one sees the result after typesetting.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `ttctexa.cls` is not a standard class. Where can it be found?

Comment: @cfr You've answered my OQ !

Comment: Sorry ...?? @user2925716

Comment: @cfr I've looked into `ttctexa.cls` and there was `\let\StartShownPreambleCommands\relax
\let\StopShownPreambleCommands\relax
`

Comment: So those commands are defined to do nothing successfully (which is what `\relax` does).